# Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create store procedure as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Test1` (IN projName VARCHAR(200), IN tablName VARCHAR(200))
  BEGIN

  set @cmd = concat('Create table', tablName ' as ( select name from   samprojects.projects  where type=',projName')');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @cmd;
  EXECUTE stmt;

  END
```

And getting below error

ERROR 1583: Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'

Any idea how to resolve this.

I am using MYSQL workbench for running sql queries

SQL script generated by MYSQL workbench is as follows

```
 USE `samprojects`;
 DROP procedure IF EXISTS `Test1`;

 DELIMITER $$
 USE `samprojects`$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE `Test1` (IN projName VARCHAR(200), IN tablName VARCHAR(200))
  BEGIN

  set @cmd = concat('Create table', tablName, ' as ( select name from   samprojects.projects  where type=',projName')');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @cmd;
  EXECUTE stmt;

  END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing a comma after `tablName`:

```
 set @cmd = concat('Create table', tablName, ' as ( select name from   samprojects.projects  where type=''',projName, ''')');
```

Comment: tried, same error - ERROR 1583: Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'

Comment: @atulya You're missing one more comma, `projName')'`  should be `projName, ')'`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, While calling store procedure getting error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tabled1 as ( select name from   samprojects.projects  where type=abcd)' at line 1

Comment: @atulya: Updated the answer. You should add extra quotes for the where clause.